# .htaccess help adusting gZip and Expires values

Tags: .htaccess, gzip

YSlow report says:
Grade F on Compress components with gzip

There are 12 plain text components that should be sent compressed

```
http://www.mysite.com/css/c/style
http://www.mysite.com/css/c/dd.css
http://www.mysite.com/css/c/jqueryslidemenu.css
http://www.mysite.com/assets/js/browser-detection.css
http://www.mysite.com/assets/js/jquery-1.6.min.js
http://www.mysite.com/assets/js/jquery.dd.js
http://www.mysite.com/images/jquery.pngFix.pack.js
http://www.mysite.com/assets/js/jqueryslidemenu.js
http://www.mysite.com/assets/js/browser-detection.js
http://www.mysite.com/assets/js/cufon-yui.js
http://www.mysite.com/assets/js/Futura_Bk_BT_400.font.js
http://www.mysite.com/store/ajax/getpubs.php
```

There are 32 static components without a far-future expiration date.

```
(2012/2/17) http://www.mysite.com/css/c/style
(2012/2/17) http://www.mysite.com/css/c/dd.css
(2012/2/17) http://www.mysite.com/css/c/jqueryslidemenu.css
(no expires) http://www.mysite.com/assets/js/browser-detection.css
(2012/2/15) http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js
(no expires) http://www.mysite.com/assets/js/jquery-1.6.min.js
(1997/7/26) http://www.mysite.com/j/banner_slides
(1997/7/26) http://www.mysite.com/j/multi-click-slider
(no expires) http://www.mysite.com/assets/js/jquery.dd.js
(no expires) http://www.mysite.com/images/jquery.pngFix.pack.js
(no expires) http://www.mysite.com/assets/js/jqueryslidemenu.js
(no expires) http://www.mysite.com/assets/js/browser-detection.js
(no expires) http://www.mysite.com/assets/js/cufon-yui.js
(no expires) http://www.mysite.com/assets/js/Futura_Bk_BT_400.font.js
(no expires) http://www.mysite.com/assets/js/fonts.js
(1997/7/26) http://www.mysite.com/j/jquerycourseslide.js
(no expires) http://www.mysite.com/images/menu_bg.png
(no expires) http://www.mysite.com/images/menuArrowYellow.png
(no expires) http://www.mysite.com/images/menuArrowGrey.png
(no expires) http://www.mysite.com/images/bgHomeBanner.png
(no expires) http://www.mysite.com/images/btnHomeBannerLeft.png
(no expires) http://www.mysite.com/images/btnHomeBannerRight.png
(no expires) http://www.mysite.com/images/btnLeft.png
(no expires) http://www.mysite.com/images/btnRight.png
(no expires) http://www.mysite.com/images/select-base.png
(no expires) http://www.mysite.com/images/select-cap.png
(no expires) http://www.mysite.com/images/iconComments.png
(no expires) http://www.mysite.com/images/bgRSS.png
(no expires) http://www.mysite.com/images/bgFooter.png
(no expires) http://www.mysite.com/files/Subscriptionad4.jpg
(no expires) http://www.mysite.com/images/favicon.ico
(2000/4/19) http://www.google-analytics.com/__utm.gif?...
```

I have this added to my .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header unset ETag
  Header unset Last-Modified
</IfModule>
FileETag None

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
  BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
  SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary
  Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
</IfModule>

<Files *.php>
  SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</Files>

<IfModule mod_gzip.c>
  mod_gzip_on Yes
  mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
  mod_gzip_item_include file \.(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
  mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
  mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
  mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
  mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
  mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive On
  ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 1 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 604800 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"
</IfModule>
```

What adjustments need to be made in order to avoid the reports above?

Note: These are links served by ExpresssionEngine as templates with no extension:

```
http://www.mysite.com/css/c/style
http://www.mysite.com/j/banner_slides
http://www.mysite.com/j/multi-click-slider
```

ExpressionEngine gZip output is set to Yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you do a hard refresh of the page (ctrl+F5). I've noticed YSlow using the cached header info, and therefor not show the correct info.

Also make sure you have the appropriate apache module enabled. Check this by removing the ifmodule tags (except for the mod_gzip one, which section you can remove entirely).

I thinks YSlow requires to has a Expires to be at least 7 days into the future, so at least 604800 seconds.

Also remove the line: `Header unset Last-Modified` unless you know what it does and have a special purpose for it.

Comment: YSlow must be using the same cache each time because I have done that and it still comes up with the same info. Could it be that expires and gzip aren't enabled on my server?

Comment: Just check the HTTP headers and see if `Expires: ...` and/or `Content-Encoding: gzip` is present